# Trouble mocking WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-webclient

I am working on writing something akin to integration tests in a Spring Boot application. The application is an API that has 3 layers - controller, service, and persistence. The tests will involve using MockMVC to call the controller methods. I don't want to mock any of the logic, only what is returned from the WebClient, and this is where my troubles lie. I have a service class that queries an external API using a WebClient, but also includes other logic, including interacting with an internal database. This means I can't just mock the service. I have tried approaches by [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mocking-webclient) (mocking each method used in the fluent API), [Stevie Leitch](https://www.dontpanicblog.co.uk/2022/01/15/testing-spring-reactive-webclient/) (mocking just the exchange function), and tried to gain insights from sources like [rieckpil.de](https://rieckpil.de/spring-webclient-exchange-vs-retrieve-a-comparison/) on differences between exchange vs retrieve methods in WebClient.

Below are how my controller and service are implemented, including specifics of my WebClient calls in my service. Can anyone give me insight on how to properly mock the WebClient so I can use MockMVC to call the controller, and have the WebClient in the service return a mocked response?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public final class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    UserController(final UserService service) {
        this.userService = service;
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getById(
        final @PathVariable String id) {
        User payload = userService.getById(id);
        return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(payload);
    }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAll() {
        List<user> payload = userService.getAll();
        return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(payload);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class UserService {

    private String url;
    private final WebClient webClient;
    private final Repository repository;

    public UserService(final WebClient webClient, final String uri, final Repository repository) {
        this.webClient = webClient;
        this.uri = uri;
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public List<User> getAll() {
        ArrayList<User> responses = webClient.get()
                .uri(uri)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<User>>() {})
                .block();
        // Other unrelated logic
        return responses;
    }

    public User getById(final String id) {
        String finalURI = uri + id;
        Optional<User> response = Optional
                .ofNullable(webClient.get()
                .uri(finalURI)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> {
                    switch (clientResponse.rawStatusCode()) {
                        case 200:
                            return clientResponse.bodyToMono(User.class);
                        case 404:
                            throw new UserNotFoundException(id);
                        default:
                            return Mono.empty();
                        }
                })
                .block());
        // Other unrelated logic
        return response.get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> We can solve any problem by introducing an extra level of indirection. [[^1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering)

Don't mock the WebClient directly. Instead, wrap it in a component which makes testing it easier:

```
public interface UserRepository {
    List<User> getAll();
    Optional<User> getById(final String id);
}

@Component
public class UserWebClientRepository implements UserRepository {

    private String uri;
    private final WebClient webClient;

    public UserService(final String uri, final WebClient webClient) {
        this.webClient = webClient;
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAll() {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri(uri)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<User>>() {})
                .block();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> getById(final String id) {
        String finalURI = uri + id;
        return Optional
                .ofNullable(webClient.get()
                .uri(finalURI)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> {
                    switch (clientResponse.rawStatusCode()) {
                        case 200:
                            return clientResponse.bodyToMono(User.class);
                        case 404:
                            throw new UserNotFoundException(id);
                        default:
                            return Mono.empty();
                        }
                })
                .block());
    }
}

@Component
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository;
    private final Repository repository;

    public UserService(final UserRepository userRepository, final Repository repository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public List<User> getAll() {
        List<User> responses = userRepository.getAll();
        // Other unrelated logic
        return responses;
    }

    public User getById(final String id) {
        Optional<User> response = userRepository.getById(id);
        // Other unrelated logic
        return response.get();
    }
}
```

This simplifies your service greatly as well and moves out persistence concerns (e.g. how to build the final URL).

When testing, you can now simply swap out the `UserRepository` with a test double, such as a Mockito mock:

```
@MockBean UserRepository userRepo;
@Autowired MockMvc mvc;

@BeforeEach
void setup() {
  when(userRepo.getAll()).thenReturn(List.of(…));
  when(userRepo.getById(anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.of(…));
}

@Test
void test() {
  mvc.perform(…)
     .…;
}
```

You don't need to test WebClient itself, it is already well-tested. And if you really want to make sure that the requests work, write an integration test which runs your `UserWebClientRepository` against a real web server.